# Jina2 tag out of line

Tags: python, jinja2

### server

```html
CKEDITOR.instances['board-content'].setData('{{ board.bo_content|replace("\n", "")|safe }}');
```

### client

```html
CKEDITOR.instances['board-content'].setData('<p>file</p> // unexpected EOF error
');
```

DB value is fine.

```html
<p>file<p>
```

Why do i get this error?

Comment: Solved. i used ``(support js multiple line).